# The difference between ip link down and physical link absence

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, ethernet, iproute

In Linux, is there any difference between ***after-`ip link down`-condition*** and ***real link absence*** (e.g. the switch's port burned down, or someone tripped over a wire).
By difference I mean some signs in the system that can be used to distinguish these two conditions.
E.g. will routing table be identical in these two cases? Will `ethtool` or something else show the same things? Is there some tool/utility which can distinguish these conditions?

Comment: Some of the formatting and use of &, seems random to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are difference between an interface which is administratively *up* but disconnected or administratively *down*.

### Disconnected

The interface gets a *carrier down* status. Its proper handling might depend on the driver for the interface and the kernel version. Normally it's available with `ip link show`. For example with a virtual ethernet *veth* interface:

```
# ip link add name vetha up type veth peer name vethb
# ip link show type veth
2: vethb@vetha: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 02:a0:3b:9a:ad:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: vetha@vethb: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state LOWERLAYERDOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 36:e3:62:1b:a8:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

*vetha* which is itself administratively UP, displays `NO-CARRIER` and the equivalent *operstate* `LOWERLAYERDOWN` flags: it's disconnected.

Equivalent `/sys/` entries exist too:

```
# cat /sys/class/net/vetha/carrier /sys/class/net/vetha/operstate
0
lowerlayerdown
```

In usual settings, for an interface which is administratively *up* the *carrier* and *operstate* match (NO-CARRIER <=> LOWERLAYERDOWN or LOWER_UP <=> UP). One exception would be for example when using IEEE 802.1X authentication (advanced details of *operstate* are described in this kernel documentation: [Operational States](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/operstates.html), but it's not needed for this explanation).

`ethtool` queries a lower level API to retrieve this same carrier status.

Having no carrier doesn't prevent any layer 3 settings to stay in effect. The kernel doesn't change addresses or routes when this happens. It's just that in the end a packet that should be emitted won't be emitted by the interface and of course no reply will come either. So for example trying to connect to an other IPv4 address will sooner or later trigger again an ARP request which will fail, and the application will receive a "No route to host". Established TCP connections will just bid their time and stay established.

### Administratively down

Above *vethb* has *operstate* DOWN and doesn't display any carrier status (since it has to be up to detect this. A physical Ethernet interface of course behaves the same).

When the interface is brought down (`ip link set ... down`), the carrier can't be detected anymore since the underlying hardware device was very possibly powered off and the operstate becomes "down". `ethtool` will just say there's no link too, so can't be used reliably for this (it will surely display a few *unknown* entries too but is there a reliable scheme for this?).

This time this will have an effect on layer 3 network settings. The kernel will refuse to add routes using this interface and will remove any previous routes related to it:

- the automatic (`proto kernel`) LAN routes added when adding an address
- any other route added (eg: the default route) in any routing table (not only the *main* routing table) depending directly on the interface (`scope link`) or on other previous deleted routes (probably then `scope global`) . As these won't reappear when the interface is brought back up (`ip link set ... up`) they are lost until an userspace tool adds them back.

### Userspace interactions

When using recent tools like NetworkManager, one can get confused and think a disconnect is similar to an interface down. That's because NM monitors links and will do actions when such events happen. To get an idea the `ip monitor` tool can be used to monitor from scripts, but it doesn't have a stable/parsable output currently (no JSON output available), so its use gets limited.

So when a wire is disconnected, NM will very likely consider it's not using the current configuration anymore unless a specific setting prevents it: it will then delete the addresses and routes itself. When the wire is connected back, NM will apply its configuration again: adds back addresses and routes (using DHCP if relevant). This looks like the same but isn't. All this time the interface stayed *up*, or it wouldn't even have been possible for NM to be warned when the connection was back.

### Summary

- It's easy to distinguish the two cases: `ip link show` will display `NO-CARRIER`+`LOWERLAYERDOWN` for a disconnected interface, and `DOWN` for an interface administratively brought down.
- setting an interface administratively down (and up) can lose routes
- losing carrier and recovering it doesn't disrupt network settings. If the delay is short enough it should not even disrupt ongoing network connections
- but applications managing network might react and change network settings, sometimes with a result similar to administratively down case
- you can use commands like `ip monitor link` to receive events about interfaces set administratively down/up or carrier changes, or `ip monitor` to receive all the multiple related events (including address or route changes) that would happen at this time or shortly after.
- Most `ip` commands (but not `ip monitor`) have a JSON output available with `ip -json ...` to help scripts (along with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)).

  Example (continuing from the first *veth* example):

  *vethb* is still down:

  ```
  # ip -j link show dev vethb | jq '.[].operstate'
  "DOWN"

  # ip -j link show dev vetha | jq '.[].operstate'
  "LOWERLAYERDOWN"
  ```

  Set *vethb* up, which now gets a carrier on both:

  ```
  # ip link set vethb up
  # ip -j link show dev vetha | jq '.[].operstate'
  "UP"
  ```

  This tells about the 3 usual states: administratively *down*, *lowerlayerdown* (ie: up but disconnected) or *up* (ie: operational).

Comment: Thanks for explanation! *"since the underlying hardware device was very possibly powered off"* - what exactly do you mean by *powered off*?

Comment: When the driver sets the interface down, it can tell the NIC to power off parts of it, in particular the physical link (it might be called the PHY layer). That's when the small green LED doesn't shine anymore on the interface. It could be more complicated though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I see in `dmesg` after running `ip link set enp3s0 down`:

```
r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
```

```
ethtool enp3s0
Settings for enp3s0:
Cannot get device settings: No such device
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: d
    Link detected: no
```

However if

> the switch's port burned down, or someone tripped over a wire

The interface must **still be there**, as well as static IP addresses and routes. `ethtool` will detect your NIC and show `Link detected: no` but the output will be complete, unlike when the device is removed via `ip l set interface down`.

Comment: I tried `ip l s dev eno1` on my Linux and it has no effect on `ethtool`'s output except these fields: **`Speed`** (`100Mb/s` ->`Unknown!`), **`Duplex`** (`Full` ->`Unknown! (255)`), **`PHYAD`** (`1` -> `2`), **`MDI-X`** (`off (auto)` ->`Unknown (auto)`) and **`Link detected`** (`yes` -> `no`). There is no problem with `Cannot get device settings: No such device` as you mentioned.

Comment: The same changes are when I pulling out the patching cord.