# Is there a way to add an IP to Linux for a link that is currently down or non-existant

Tags: linux, networking

As is mentioned multiple times here on U&L, Linux only losely binds an IP address to an interface.  If you have a Linux machine with eth0 on 192.168.1.23/24 and eth1 on 10.10.10.55/24, you can easily ping 192.168.1.23 from eth1 just as long as your other host knows where to send the packets.

---

This is actually useful sometimes.  For example when setting up VPNs, it is not necessary to configure a network segment (range of IPs) for the VPN itself.

Host A has eth0 IP 192.168.1.1/24

Host B has eth0 IP 10.10.10.1/24

Both host A and host B have a wg0 interface (wireguard VPN) connected to each other.  Host A is configured to route 10.10.10.0/24 via wg0, and Host B is configured to route 192.168.1.0/24 via wg0...

... Thus the VPN itself, doesn't need it's own IP allocation and neither host have an IP associated with wg0.  Yes this works!

---

The question is what happens if a fault develops on eth0 or it's simply unplugged.  Linux will remove the IP address and will suddenly stop responding to the VPN all togeather.

Is this a strong reason to add a network segment for the VPN and add an addational VPN IP address to every router, or is there some way to add an IP address to linux without associating it with any Link?

Comment: Associate it with the loopback interface. That one's not likely to go down for outside reasons.

Comment: Not useful but to correct a possible misconception, unplugging does not remove an address (but NetworkManager might): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/619068/the-difference-between-ip-link-down-and-physical-link-absence

Comment: @A.B Thanks, do I read that correctly though that a link that is gone (not the ethernet cable but the whole device) would remove the ip. I guess unplugging a USB Ethernet adapter might be an example.

Comment: Correct. As wrote ikkachu this won't happen with lo.